# Output the ALONED numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

Consider the natural sequence up-to 6 *(disregard 1)*:

```
2,3,4,5,6
```

We start scanning from the left (in this case from 2), search for a number divisible by 2 (here 4) and then remove both the numbers from the list (here 2 & 4), such that the list reduces to:

```
3,5,6
```

We continue the same process, here leftmost is 3, so we search for number divisible by 3. 6 is surely that number and thus 3 and 6 are removed,

```
5
```

Now, no further such searches can be made Thus, this becomes the list of ALONED numbers for n=6.

**OBJECTIVE**

1. Given a number n greater than 1, print all the corresponding aloned numbers.

**INPUT**

```
2
6
15
20
22
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2
5
8,9,11,12,13,15
11,12,13,15,17,19,20
12,13,15,17,19,20,21
```

**YET ANOTHER WORKED OUT EXAMPLE**

*For n= 22*

```
=>2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
=>3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 (remove 2 & 4)
=>5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 (remove 3 & 6)
=>7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 (remove 5 & 10)
=>8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 (remove 7 & 14)
=>9,11,12,13,15,17,18,19,20,21,22 (remove 8 & 16)
=>11,12,13,15,17,19,20,21,22 (remove 9 & 18)
=>12,13,15,17,19,20,21 (remove 11 & 22) (OUTPUT)
```

***This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.***

Comment: Just so you know, we have a [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where you can post incomplete challenges for feedback before posting it to the main site.

Comment: Do we have to return a list of the numbers in ascending order or would an unordered list or a set be acceptable as well?

Comment: should be in ascending order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>22</s> <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
L¦¹F¬·©¹›_i¦®K
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TMKmwrlGwqzCt8KpwrnigLpfacKmwq5L&input=MjI)

**Explanation**

```
L¦               # push the list [2..input]
  ¹F             # input nr of times do:
          i      # if
    ¬·©          # the first element in the list * 2
       ¹›_       # is less than or equal to input
                 # then
           ¦     # remove first element of list
            ®K   # and remove it's multiple
```

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, <s>90</s> <s>79</s> 73 bytes

<sup>*-6 bytes thanks to xnor*</sup>

```
L=range(2,input()+1)
while L[0]*2<=L[-1]:L.remove(L[0]*2);L=L[1:]
print L
```

Takes the input number on stdin. [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/GXFLiX)

#### Explanation

We construct the initial list from the input number and store it in `L`. Next, loop while the last number is greater than or equal to 2 times the first number and remove 2 times the first number from the list. This will always be the next number divisible by `L[0]`. `L=L[1:]` takes off the first number as well. When the condition is no longer true, no further removals can be made, and the list is printed.

Comment: In Python 2, `range` already gives a list.

Comment: @xnor Thanks! Forgot about that.

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 61 bytes

```python
lambda n:[i+1for i in range(n/2,n)if-~i&~i&4**n/3>>(-~i&i<1)]
```

It's a bit easier to understand this less golfed code:

```python
lambda n:[i for i in range(n/2+1,n+1)if((i&-i)**.5%1>0)^(i&~-i>0)]
```

This uses a direct characterization of aloned numbers:

> A number `i` is *aloned* if, when decomposed as `i = a * 2^b` with `b` odd, either
>
> - `a>1` and `b` is even, or
> - `a==1` and `b` is odd
>
> The aloned numbers for `n` are all aloned numbers `i` in the interval `n/2 + 1 <= i <= n`.

Why does this hold? When doing the process for `n`, say we remove an odd number `a` in the lower half (`1` to `n/2`). Then, `2*a` is removed no matter where in the list it is. So, `4*a` remains (if it existed). But if it's in the lower half, the deletion process will get to it and remove both `4*a` and `8*a`. So, we see that an upper-half number gets removed if it's of form `2*a`, `8*a` ... with odd `c`, but stays if it has form `a`, `4*a`, `8*a`, ...

The exception is for `a=1`, which does not start in the list and so is not removed. As a result, the removal chain starts with `a=2`, and the rule for powers of 2 is flipped.

```python
lambda n:[i for i in range(n/2+1,n+1)if((i&-i)**.5%1>0)^(i&~-i>0)]
```

In the code above, `(i&-i)**.5%1>0` checks whether `i` lacks the form `i = a * 2^b` with `b` odd, by the bit-trick to extract the greatest power-of-two factor, `2^b = i&-i`, then checking if the result is not a perfect square. Then, `i&~-i>0` is another bit trick to check if `i` is not a perfect power of 2. These conditions are then xor'ed.

There's some more improvements here

```python
lambda n:[i+1for i in range(n/2,n)if-~i&~i&4**n/3>>(-~i&i<1)]
```

First, we shift the range 1 index down to to shorten to `range(n/2,n)` from `range(n/2+1,n+1)`, compensating by replacing all `i` with `i+1` (or `~-i`).

Whether a power of 2 is number is a power of `4` (2^`b` with `b` even) can be checked by and-ing with `2**c/3` for some large `c`. This is because `2**c/3` has binary representation `10101...101` with ones in the even-positioned bits. Using `c=2*n` suffices. To negate result when `i` is a power of 2, we halve this number is that case, putting `1`'s in the odd positions instead.

Answer (score 4):

## Groovy, <s>65</s> 58 Bytes

Algorithm idea from [DSLoc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96966/59376), who noticed you need only to remove the doubles.

```
{n->a=(2..n);(2..(n/2)).each{if(it in a){a-=[it,it*2]}};a}
```

Here's a breakdown:

```
{
    n->
    a=(2..n);             // Store [2,...,n].
    (2..(n/2)).each {     // From 2 to half of n.
        if(it in a){      // If it's there...
            a-=[it,it*2]  // Remove it and its double, store in a.
        }
    };
    a                     // Return a.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>53</s> <s>49</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

Includes +1 for `-n`

Give input number on STDIN:

```
perl -M5.010 aloned.pl <<< 22
```

`aloned.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
@F[$F[$_*2]/2,$_*2,1]=0,$_&&say for@F=0..$_
```

Directly checking the possible numbers is longer:

```
map{/$/;$_/=4until$_%4;$_%2^$_<3&&say$`}$_/2+1..$_
```

This checks all numbers in the upper half range. Keep numbers that have an even number of 2 as prime factors except if the number is a power of 2 then odd (because 1 is left out of the original series). This method should however work well for other languages.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>71</s> <s>69</s> <s>62</s> 56 bytes

```
g(a:b)|s<-filter(/=2*a)b=[a|s==b]++g s
g x=x
q n=g[2..n]
```

Usage example: `q 22` -> `[12,13,15,17,19,20,21]`.

If there's a multiple of the first number `a`, then it's `2*a`. Keep `a` if `2*a` is not in the list and append a recursive call with `a` and `2*a` removed from the list.

Comment: Hehe, I was going to tell you that GCD was overkill, but you got it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 18 bytes

*Borrowed the "multiply by 2" idea from [@Emigna's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96971/36398)*.

```
q:Qt"t1)tEhym?6MX-
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cTpRdCJ0MSl0RWh5bT82TVgt&input=MjI)

#### Explanation

```
q:Q        % Input n implicitly. Push [2 3 ... n]
t"         % Duplicate. For each: repeat n-1 times
  t1)      %   Duplicate. Get first element from current array, say k
  tEh      %   Append twice that value: gives array [k 2*k]
  y        %   Push another copy of current array
  m?       %   If both k and 2*k are members of the array 
    6M     %     Push [k 2*k] again
     X-    %     Set difference: remove from current array
           %   End if implicitly
           % End for each implicitly
           % Display implicitly
```

Comment: You need only check if k is a member, don't know if that saves you a bytes or not.

Comment: @carusocomputing Thanks! I initially checked only 2*k (if that's what you mean). Then I added k there because later on I reuse that array of two elements to remove both from the general array

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 19 bytes

Will *definitely* be refactoring.

```
u?Kf!%ThGtG-tGhKGtS
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3FKf%21%25ThGtG-tGhKGtS&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A6%0A15%0A20%0A22&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 124

Comparing scores to other answers, this is obviously the wrong approach:

```ruby
->n{a={};b=[*2..n].each{|k|a[k]=7}
b.map{|i|g=b.select{|x|a[i]&&a[x]&&x%i<1}
a[g[0]]=a[g[1]]=!g[1]}
a.select{|k,v|v&k}.keys}
```

The somewhat clever bit here is `a[g[0]]=a[g[1]]=!g[1]` which sets the hash's values to true/false as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 98 Bytes

```
foreach($r=range(2,$argv[1])as$v)$a=&$r[$v-2]&&$b=&$r[$v*2-2]?$b=$a="":(!$a?:print$x?",$a":$x=$a);
```

8 Bytes save by [@Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) Thank You

If a trailing comma is allowed then it can be shorten 9 Bytes
`(!$a?:print"$a,");` instead of `(!$a?:print$x?",$a":$x=$a);`

Comment: Don´t the assignments to `$a` and `$b` need parentheses? Wicked!

Comment: -1 byte with the trailing comma: `(!$a?:print"$a,")` -> `print$a?"$a,":""`. -2 bytes for both versions if you use the underscore as separator.

Comment: -2 bytes: `foreach(... as$v)`, `$v-2` instead of `$k` and `$v*2-2` instead of `$k*2+2`.

Comment: @Titus I have tried it after you comment `$a=&$r[$k]&&$b=&$r[$k*2+2]` works like `$a=$r[$k]and$b=$r[$k*2+2]`. I am sorry about I found no page which explains combinations with references and the `&&` operator. But I need references not assignments. I'm not sure if a trailing comma or an other separator is allowed.

Comment: @Titus  found it now http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php `&` bitwise and references haves a higher Precedence then the `&&` operator

Comment: Yea; they finally updated my favorite page in the manual; but I didn´t notice that until now. You can still take the two bytes. ;)

Comment: and -6 bytes: `(!$a?:print$x?",$a":$x=$a);` instead of `(!$a?:$t[]=$a);echo join(",",$t);`

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 149 bytes

```
function a(n){o=Array.from(Array((n+1)).keys());o.shift();o.shift();for(i=1;i<o.length;i++){if(o[i]%o[0]==0){o.splice(i,1);o.shift();i=0;}}return o;}
```

Here's a working example. All the HTML and the wrapper() function is just so it's actually interactive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Aloned</title>
<script>
  function wrapper(){document.getElementById("o").innerHTML = a(parseInt(document.getElementById("i").value));}
  function a(n){o=Array.from(Array((n+1)).keys());o.shift();o.shift();for(i=1;i<o.length;i++){if(o[i]%o[0]==0){o.splice(i,1);o.shift();i=0;}}return o;}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>Enter an integer:</p>
<p><input type="text" id="i" value="5" /></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Alone It!" onclick="wrapper()" /></p>
<div id="o"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This ungolfed code snippet has some comments and lets you interactively see the steps for any given input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Aloned</title>
<script>
  function wrapper()
  {
    document.getElementById("o").innerHTML = aloned(parseInt(document.getElementById("i").value));
  }
  function aloned(n)
  {
    // From nils peterson's comment on benmcdonald's answer
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478
    // Creates an array from 0 to n.
    o=Array.from(Array((n+1)).keys());
    
    // Remove 0 and 1 from the start of the array.
    o.shift();
    o.shift();
    
    // s and t are just used to display the output each iteration.
    var s = String(o);
    
    // Go through every item in the array (except the first).
    for(i = 1; i < o.length; i++)
    {
      // Check for an item evenly divisible by the first item.
      if (o[i]%o[0]==0)
      {
        var t=" (remove "+o[0]+" and "+o[i]+")";
        
        // Splice removes the current item, shift removes the first item.
        o.splice(i,1);
        o.shift();
        
        // Reset the array, so we're looping from the beginning again.
        i=0;
        
        s = s + "<br />" + String(o) + t;
      }
    }
    return s + " (OUTPUT)";
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>Enter an integer:</p>
<p><input type="text" id="i" value="5" /></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Alone It!" onclick="wrapper()" /></p>
<div id="o"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 191 bytes

```
(let loop((fl(range 2(add1 n)))(fg #f))(define i(first fl))(for((j(rest fl))
#:when(= 0(modulo j i))#:final(= 0(modulo j i)))
(set! fl(remove*(list i j)fl))(set! fg #t))(if fg(loop fl #f)fl))
```

Ungolfed (comments after ';'):

```
(define (f n)
  (let loop ((fl (range 2 (add1 n)))  ; create a full list of numbers
             (fg #f))                 ; flag to show if main list is modified
    (define i (first fl))
    (for ((j (rest fl)) #:when (= 0 (modulo j i))  ; test divisibility
                        #:final (= 0 (modulo j i)))
      (set! fl (remove* (list i j) fl))  ; remove these from main list
      (set! fg #t))
    (if fg (loop fl #f)              ; if main list modified, check again,
        fl)))                         ; else print modified list.
```

Testing:

```
(f 2)
(f 6)
(f 15)
(f 20)
(f 22)
```

Output:

```
'(2)
'(5)
'(8 9 11 12 13 15)
'(11 12 13 15 17 19 20)
'(12 13 15 17 19 20 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```
f=(n,R=[...Array(n-1)].map((_,i)=>i+2),[i,...r]=R)=>~r.indexOf(i*=2)?f(n,r.filter(x=>x-i)):R
```

I thought I had posted this yesterday, but obviously not...

Here's another version:

```
f=(n,R=[...Array(n-1)].map((_,i)=>i+2),[i,...r]=R,q=r.filter(x=>x-i*2))=>q+""!=r+""?f(n,q):R
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 210 bytes

```
import java.util.*;List c(int n){List<Integer>l=new ArrayList();int i=1;for(;i++<n;l.add(i));for(i=1;i++<n;)for(int x:l)if(i!=x&x%i<1&l.indexOf(i)>=0){l.remove((Integer)i);l.remove((Integer)x);break;}return l;}
```

Can definitely be golfed some more by using a different approach, probably by using an array with some tricks. Due to the cast, break, typed-list and if-checks it is a bit longer than expected, but it works.

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/EDldZq)

```
import java.util.*;
class M{
  static List c(int n){
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList();
    int i = 1;
    for(; i++ < n; l.add(i));
    for(i = 1; i++ < n;){
      for(int x : l){
        if(i != x & x%i < 1 & l.indexOf(i) >= 0){
          l.remove((Integer)i);
          l.remove((Integer)x);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return l;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c(2).toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c(6).toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c(15).toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c(20).toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c(22).toArray()));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2]
[5]
[8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15]
[11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20]
[12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21]
```